# Improvement of storage management in bit sort algorithm

Tags: matlab, sorting, memory-management

from  the book of  programming pearls,  i  have  read information about bit sort algorithm, here is its simple  example in matlab

```
function result=bit_sort(A)
% given array of integers, sort  element of A using bit sort
max_element=max(A); % find maximum element of A
b=zeros(max_element,1);
result=zeros(size(A));
n=length(A);
for ii=1:n
    b(A(ii))=1;
end
k=1;
for ii=1:max_element
    if b(ii)==1
        result(k)=ii;
        k=k+1;
    end
end
end
```

here is also example that it works well

```
A=[2 1 3 6 5 4 9 7];
>> result=bit_sort(A)

result =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     9
```

another example

```
a=[2 1 4 100];
>> result=bit_sort(a)

result =

     1     2     4   100
```

code works fine, but  i have  a different question : in code declaration of this  line

```
max_element=max(A); % find maximum element of A
b=zeros(max_element,1);
```

occupies another  part of memory  which in some cases may not be necessary, for instance when i have  4 element :1 2 4 100 , how can i  do  effectively array declaration so that   i can achieve two condition : 1.  effective memory management 2.keep  constant speed of my algorithm ?thanks in  advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the loop to create the initial array of zeros and ones *or* to locate the positions of the `1`'s. Instead we can use `ismember` and `find` to yield the result

```
function result = bit_sort(x)    
    result = find(ismember(1:max(x), x));
end
```

**Explanation**

`ismember` checks if each entry in the first input are present in the second input. In your case, since we want an array that has an entry for every number between 1 and `max(x)` and we want the value to be `true` if the value is in `x` and `false` otherwise, we can do

```
tmp = ismember(1:max(x), x)
%  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
```

Then we can use `find` to get the *locations* of each of the 1's in the above array

```
find(tmp)
%  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   9
```

**Some other alternatives**

Rather than using `ismember`, you can rely on the fact that in MATLAB if you assign to an empty array using indices, any index that you don't specify will receive the default value of `0`, we can therefore create your array of 1's and 0's using

```
tmp(x) = true;          % Create a logical array
result = find(tmp);     % Again, use find to get the indices
```

The benefit of this solution is that you don't have to create the array `1:max(x)` therefore saving memory. Also, `tmp` is a `logical` array instead of a `double` so it takes up 8x less space than `b` in your example.

Comment: thanks  guys for your help, about storage  ?i mean  does this changing  improves  storage  usage ?

Comment: @datodatuashvili As I said in the last part of my answer, if you go with my approach it uses `logical` arrays which are smaller than the `double` arrays that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here is an implementation using actual bit vectors. The size of the bit vector is `ceil(max_element/8)` bytes, which is approximately 1/64 the size of a double array or 1/8 the size of a logical array. It is also probably slower than the other implementations. It is still `O(n)`, but the constant has no doubt increased.

```
function result = bit_sort(A)
% given array of integers, sort  element of A using bit sort
% integers must be strictly positive
   max_element = max(A);   % find maximum element of A
   bitvec_size = ceil(max_element/8);   % 8 bits per uint8
   b = zeros(bitvec_size, 1, 'uint8');
   result = zeros(size(A));
   n = length(A);
   for ii=1:n
       current_num = A(ii) - 1;   % account for 1-based indexing
       byte_num = idivide(current_num, 8) + 1;   % find byte for our value
       % set bit # mod(n, 8) in byte found above
       %    add one again for 1-based bit indexing
       b(byte_num) = bitset(b(byte_num), mod(current_num, 8) + 1);
   end
   k = 1;
   for bytenum = 1:bitvec_size
      for bitnum = 1:8
         if bitget(b(bytenum), bitnum)
            result(k) = (bytenum-1)*8 + bitnum;   % bitnum = bitnum - 1 + 1
                                                  % I love 1-based indexing
            k = k + 1;
         end
      end
   end
end
```

For each value in the input array, this finds the byte number (index) into the vector by dividing the value by 8 using integer division. Then the bit in that byte found by the value mod 8 is set. At each step it is necessary to adjust for 1-based indexing. Interestingly, you could instead use `ind2sub` to find the index and bit numbers, but that would be even more arcane.

You could achieve the same thing a number of different ways, with `bit_or` and `bitshift`, maybe `bi2de` for decoding. I don't know if they'd be faster or not, but the main goal here was to show a way to reduce the memory usage for the bit vector `b`.

One more *minor* optimization you can make if you know that the minimum array value is much larger than 1 is to use the minimum value as the base of the array. That would only really make sense if the min value is around half (or more) of the max value, in which case you could at least halve the size of the bit vector.

Comment: god bless you ,tomorrow i  will go in detail

Answer (score 2):

If number of elements of A is much smaller than max A more efficient way is  using sparse matrix:

```
find(sparse(A,1,A));
```

or more efficient:

```
find(sparse(A,1,true));
```

Comment: and will  it sort array?

Answer (score 1):

here is vectorized version of the same code

```
function result=bit_sort_vecorized(A)
% vectorized version
b(A(1:end))=1;
result=zeros(size(A));
n=length(b);
k=1;
for ii=1:n
    if b(ii)==1
        result(k)=ii;
        k=k+1;
    end
end
end


 A=[2 1 3 6 5 4 9 7];
>> result=bit_sort_vecorized(A)

result =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     9
```

Answer (score 1):

1) First of all you can go further using vectorization:
replace this code

```
k=1;
for ii=1:n
    if b(ii)==1
        result(k)=ii;
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

with this one:

```
result = find( b == 1);
```

2) About calculation speed:
I used this loop for `b = randi(10,1,100000)` and get this one:

using your loop `Elapsed time is 0.019176 seconds.`

avoiding loop  --   `Elapsed time is 0.015142 seconds.`

So there is no really significant advantage.

Comment: Running code once isn’t a good way to profile, especially with a JIT compiler. Anyway, your timings suggest a relative speed-up of almost 25%. That may be significant indeed.